# How to find the integration limits of a simple unit step function convolved with itself

Tags: calculus, integration, inequality, convolution

Let the function $f$ be defined as

$f(t) =
\begin{cases}
1  & \text{if}\,\, \lvert t\rvert \le 0.5  \\
0 & \text{if}\,\, \lvert t\rvert \gt 0.5
\end{cases}$

I need to find the convolution of $f(t)$ with itself, $(f\ast f)(t)$.

I am trying to learn convolution from 'first principles', and this is the most basic example I could find with a definite answer (which is what my question will be about).

---

The word for word solution to this question is as follows:

> We need to calculate 
>   $$(f \ast f)(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(\tau)f(t-\tau)\,\mathrm{d}\tau$$
>   The integral will only get contributions when both parts in the multiplication are non-zero. Hence, for a given $t$, we should only consider values of $\tau$ that satisfy
>   $$f(\tau)\ne 0\quad\implies \quad\lvert \tau \rvert\lt 0.5$$
>   $$f(t-\tau)\ne 0\quad\implies \quad\lvert t-\tau \rvert\lt 0.5$$
>   $\color{blue}{\text{The integration should be between the limits that satisfy both conditions}}\,$ $\color{blue}{\text{which can be drawn as two crossing bands in the}}$ $\color{blue}{t}$ $\color{blue}{\text{vs.}}$ $\color{blue}{\tau}$ $\color{blue}{\text{plane.}}$
>
> - If $t \gt 1$, there are no $\tau$ satisfying the criteria and $(f*f)(t)=0$
> - $\color{red}{\text{If}}$ $\color{red}{0 \le t \le 1}$$\color{red}{\text{,}}$ $\color{red}{\text{then we see that}}$ $\color{red}{\tau}$ $\color{red}{\text{between}}$ $\color{red}{t-0.5}$ $\color{red}{\text{and}}$ $\color{red}{0.5}$ $\color{red}{\text{satisfy all criteria and we have}}$
>     $$(f \ast f)(t)=\int_{t-0.5}^{0.5}1\,\mathrm{d}\tau=(0.5-(t-0.5))=1-t$$

---

I understand everything in the solution apart from the text marked red and blue.

Put simply, I have no idea how the author deduced that $\tau$ can only take values between $t-0.5$ and $0.5$. I can't even **verify** that $\tau$ takes on these values only; starting from $$0 \le t \le 1$$ and subtracting $0.5$ from both sides gives $$-0.5 \le \underbrace{t-0.5}_{\tau} \le 0.5$$ so $$-0.5 \le \tau \le 0.5$$ but this doesn't verify that $$t-0.5 \le \tau \le 0.5$$ This question is less important but could someone please explain how I can simply verify that $$t-0.5 \le \tau \le 0.5?$$

---

**Main questions:**

[$\color{red}{\mathrm{red}}$ part] How was the author able to deduce that $\tau$ **must** be between $t-0.5$ and $0.5$?

[$\color{blue}{\mathrm{blue}}$ part] I don't suppose there is anyone out there that could generate a graph and show these "crossing bands" in the $t$ versus $\tau$ plane? I may be able to understand the logic better with this. I'm struggling to do this because $t$ and $\tau$ are both variables themselves and independent of each other. So how could I possibly sketch $t$ versus $\tau$ if $t$ does not depend on $\tau$?

Many thanks.

Comment: There is an easy and mechanistic way to find the limits of convolution.  I myself found it very handy.  Here you go!! There is a link in this answer that I gave and will come in helpful https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2719888/pdf-of-sum-of-random-variables-with-uniform-distribution/2720201#2720201

Comment: @Satish Well thank you, but I'm finding it a little hard to follow at the moment. Would you mind making an answer to this question that employs the method you used in the link you gave? If you put your method into context with this question it will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I am going define the bounds

$t_{X_0} = -0.5$

$t_{X_1} = 0.5$

$t_{W_0} = -0.5$

$t_{W_1} = +.05$

Thus $$f_Z(z) = 0, z \le t_{X_0}+t_{W_0} ,$$

$$f_Z(z) = \int_{max(t_{W_0}, z-t_{X_1})}^{min(t_{W_1}, z-t_{X_0})} f_W(w)f_X(z-w)dw,    \text{     }     t_{X_0}+t_{W_0} \le z \le t_{X_1}+t_{W_1},$$

$$f_Z(z) = 0, z \ge t_{X_1}+t_{W_1} ,$$

These translate to the following:

$$f_Z(z) = 0, z \le -1 ,$$

$$f_Z(z) = \int_{max(-0.5, z-0.5)}^{min(0.5, z+0.5)} f_W(w)f_X(z-w)dw,    \text{     }     -1\le z \le 1,$$

$$f_Z(z) = 0, z \ge 1 ,$$

$$f_W(w)=f_X(x) = 1, as |w|,|x|\le 0.5 $$

$$f_W(w)=f_X(x) = 0 , as |w|,|x|\gt 0.5 $$

The middle one needs to be split into two intervals, and they are a) $-1\le z\le 0$, b) $0\le z\le 1$.
Thus 
$$f_Z(z) = 0, z \le -1 ,$$

$$f_Z(z) = \int_{-0.5}^{z+0.5}1.1 dw = 1+z , -1\le z\le 0$$

$$f_Z(z) = \int_{z-0.5}^{0.5} 1.1 dw = 1-z, 0\le z\le 1$$

$$f_Z(z) = 0, z \ge 1 ,$$

In other words

$$f_Z(z) = 0, |z| \ge 1 ,$$

$$f_Z(z) = 1-|z|, |z| \lt 1 ,$$

If you concentrate on the intervals you will clearly see this is the case.

Comment: @SatishThank you very much indeed for this answer, however, I cannot accept it yet until it gets some more validation. In other words, no-one (except me) has upvoted your answers to this question and that other answer you gave linked to that other question. Its almost as though the other SE users think this method may be unnecessarily complicated (I'm just guessing here though)? I'm grateful that you took the time to write this answer, but I still think there must be a simpler way of carrying out the convolution by using understanding instead of an algorithmic mechanistic method. Thanks again.